# Typescript is there an easier way to initlaize?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to initialze a class in typescript that has functions, I do not want to copy the method definition each time to initialize an object. and I do not like the massive constructor, This is my class

```
export class ISelectInputOption {

    title: string;
    subTitle: string;
    mode: string;
    options: Array<EnumOption>;
    resolveName(id: number): string {

        var option = this.options.filter(option => option.id == id);

        if (option && option.length > 0) {
            return option[0].name;
        }
        return '';
    }
};
```

I have a seperate file which is initializing these I want to do this but this is not allowed:

```
priceTypeOptions: ISelectInputOption = = new ISelectInputOption()
{
    title: 'Payment Frequencies',
    subTitle: 'Select the frequency',
    mode: 'md',
    options: [{ id: 0, name: 'None', description: 'No Option' }]
};
```

is there an easier way to initialize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a similar initialization pattern:

```
let priceTypeOptions: ISelectInputOption = Object.assign(new ISelectInputOption, {
    title: 'Payment Frequencies',
    subTitle: 'Select the frequency',
    mode: 'md',
    options: [{ id: 0, name: 'None', description: 'No Option' }]
});
```

---

Another option you can try is to use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties):

Change your class definition to:

```
export class ISelectInputOption {

    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public subTitle: string,
        public mode: string,
        public options: Array<EnumOption>
    ) {

    }
    // ...
};
```

And initialize it like:

```
let priceTypeOptions: ISelectInputOption = new ISelectInputOption(
    'Payment Frequencies',
    'Select the frequency',
    'md',
    [{ id: 0, name: 'None', description: 'No Option' }]
);
```

Comment: Object assign is perfect